# Show that $|f(x)\frac{b-a}{(x-a)(x-b)}|\leq \int_a^b|f''(x)|dx$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need help with the following exercice:

Suppose that $f\in C^2[a,b]$, and $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Show that
$|f(x)\frac{b-a}{(x-a)(x-b)}|\leq \int_a^b|f''(x)|dx$.

The best I can get is the following, which is not enough: choose an $x\in [a,(a+b)/2]$, then there exists $\xi\in (a,x)$ such that
$|f(x)\frac{b-a}{(x-a)(x-b)}|=|f'(\xi)\frac{b-a}{x-b}|$. Since $f(a)=f(b)=0$, we know that there exists $\eta\in[a,b]$ such that $f'(\eta)=0$. And therefore for some $\lambda$ between $\xi$ and $\eta$, $|f'(\xi)\frac{b-a}{x-b}|=|f''(\lambda)(\xi-\eta)\frac{b-a}{x-b}|\leq |2f''(\lambda)(\xi-\eta)|\leq 2|f''(\lambda)|(b-a)$.

Comment: I dont know if it helps, but $f''(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then attains a minimum, that is, there is $m \in [a,b]$ such that $f''(m) \leq f''(x)$ for any $x \in [a,b]$. So, $|f''(m)|(b-a)  = \int_{a}^{b}|f''(m)|dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}|f''(x)|dx$.

Comment: You should try Taylor's theorem with the integral form of the remainder